# AWS S3 empty bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have all my user permission needs covered using IAM, therefore I keep my bucket policy sections completely empty.

I was wondering if this is a good practice and if it raises any potential issues from any perspective.

Perhaps there is some configuration that is good to set as default?

Just double checking.

Comment: If your org requires KMS encrypting bucket objects, you can set a bucket policy to ensure enforcement of that but otherwise management on the user/role end is just fine.

Comment: Using IAM role based access policy is probably always the way to go. Can't think of any situation where you could do access managing with Role and "prefered" way would be not to use the role. Usually if you can go away with Role, you should use role. Let it be S3 or logging to AWS Console, running VM or Lambda etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically:

- When you want to grant 'public' access to an Amazon S3 bucket, use a Bucket Policy
- When you want to grant access to specific IAM Users, attach an IAM policy to the IAM Users or IAM Groups

It sounds like your needs are satisfied via IAM policies, so that's perfectly good (and actually preferable!).